# Uploadify - How to upload contents of a folder recursively

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, paperclip, uploadify

I need to upload files in a folder recursively.

Is it possible to use Uploadify to upload contents of a folder recursively by selecting the folder instead of selecting individual files in a folder?

Answer (score 0):

I would not think so. The browser is in control of the file selection dialog (which will not allow you to select folders, only files).

*I have not tried the file drag-drop feature of the paid Uploadifive (HTML 5 version), but it might support dragging a folder. Not sure what HTML 5 allows with with drag-drop*